# How to get rid the mold smell in old canvas tent?

Tags: gear, tents, gear-care, canvas, mold

Bought a 30 year old classic Coleman's canvas ten cheap (it's Canadian cousin actually). It is in great working condition, water proofing and zippers etc. and I thought convert it to a hot tent.

But, it has been sitting in the attic for 25 years so it have a strong moldy smell. I tried rinse, sun-dry and marinated it in baking soda, no luck.

Any other method/product I should try to rid the smell?

Comment: Removed mold with Hydrogen peroxide but the smell is still there. So this question focus on the odor part.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/542/how-do-you-remove-mold-from-a-tent

Comment: Fabreeze, or a similar odor eliminating product? So long as you check it won't get rid of the water-proofing. We killed some mold in our tent with vinegar, then aired that smell out by leaving it pitched a few days,

Comment: What is a hot tent?  Heated tent?

Comment: Yeah, sew a chimney sleeve and build/buy a tent stove then I can have heat and hot food without worry about CO.

Comment: I don’t have enough for an answer but just a recommendation. Make sure that, whatever you choose, it won’t leave ANY odors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buy pure clove oil from a health food store. It comes in small, brown glass bottles of 10-20 ml or so. Add the whole contents to a half litre spray bottle of cleaning liquid, ie detergent. Shake vigorously and spray around the interior. 
I have used this in damp storage containers and the smell disappears in minutes. I have to repeat it if the container gets damp again as the mould spores are impregnated in the surface and germinate immediately. I use a an electric fan while I am spraying to help spread the spray.

Comment: Will give a try next spring~ and update result here.